# Using elasticsearch aggregations on script_field values?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created groovy script to calculate new field values.  I then can use that script in my queries to calculate the new field value using a `script_fields` parameter.  Here is an example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {"match_all": {}}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields":{
        "my_field":{
            "script_id":"my_field_calculator",
            "lang" : "groovy",
            "params": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine and I see results that each have a `fields` object containing `my_field` in it.  Perfect.

Now I want to use a [terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get the counts of each occurrence of this new field value, something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {"match_all": {}}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields":{
        "my_field":{
            "script_id":"my_field_calculator",
            "lang" : "groovy",
            "params": {}
        }
    }
    "aggs": {
        "counts_by_my_field": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "my_field"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query runs just fine and I still see my calculated results in every field, however the `aggregations` object contains one key, `counts_by_my_field`, with an empty `buckets` array inside.

What am I missing?  Is it possible to use script_fields in aggregations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I have not been able to make an aggregation use a `script_field` value for the aggregation, I have discovered another way of accomplishing what I had hoped to do.  It turns out that the aggregation will accept a `script_id` configuration that can calculate the script field value during aggregation.

Here is my example working with the `script_id` as part of the aggregation instead:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": { "match_all": {}}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "counts_by_my_field": {
            "terms": {
                "script_id": "my_field_calculator",
                "lang" : "groovy",
                "params": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible, not yet. **script_fields** dont work when placed as `field` in aggregation or in facet.

And there is no any method to access script fields by aggregations. See explanation.

I digged into Elasticsearch implementation code,

Here is Javadoc for, [ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder#script()](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java) used by Terms aggregation for scripting .

> Sets the script which generates the values. If the script is
>   configured along with the field (as in {@link #field(String)}), then
>        * this script will be treated as a {@code value script}. A *value script* will be applied on the values that are extracted
>   from
>        * the field data (you can refer to that value in the script using the {@code _value} reserved variable). If only the script is
>   configured
>        * (and the no field is configured next to it), then the script will be responsible to generate the values that will be aggregated.
>        *

This means, you cannot send "script_id" either to the aggregations. You can only do this,

```
POST index/type/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "name": {
         "terms": {
            "script": "_source.data[0]",
            "lang": "groovy",
            "params": {}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!! Thanks